# How to package and add to tool to Kali-rolling repositories?

Tags: apt, kali-linux, repository

I have created a framework that helps in penetration testing a while ago and It's pretty spreading.

How could I package that framework and add/send it to Kali repositories?

I have searched and asked a lot till a security researcher I know told me that it could be done the same way in Debian! 
I don't know how is that is done so any one could help?

By the way, the framework is in this page https://en.kali.tools/all I don't know if that matters or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably will need to have your own [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71510/how-do-i-create-a-ppa), this way you will be able to upload your sources to that specific repository and then the kali team will see if they add it to the "official" repo lists or not.